# Using TikZ's foreach loop to write a square of numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to draw the following square of numbers:

6 7 8
3 4 5
0 1 2

For this purpose I wrote the following LaTeX code, and saved it in the file `~\test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz \foreach \r in {0,1,2}
      \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \n using {\r*3+\c}] in {0,1,2}
      \node at (\c,\r) {\n};
\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

the execution of the `pdflatex` command fails, and `~\test.log` contains the following snippet:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/foreach/2' and I am going 
to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 ...\r*3+\c}] in {0,1,2} \node at (\c,\r) {\n};
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 ...\r*3+\c}] in {0,1,2} \node at (\c,\r) {\n};
                                                  
End of file on the terminal!
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi!  You must use `{...}` for each `\foreach` command after the loop list: `\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}{...}`.  You may change `\tikz` into `\begin{ticzpicture}...`.  Finally, to get the desired table, you must use `{int(\r*3+\c)}` to get integers.

Comment: @DanielN Thanks. Now it works!

Comment: @DanielN you should add an answer --- the fact that the `foreach` is not creating a grup by itself is interesting.

Comment: It seems that the above works fine without `using`. Even using `evaluate` without `using` works without the need for groups. I am unsure why this is. Probably due to the braces after `using`. Anyways, you can fix your code by placing the second `\foreach` macro insinde a group using curly braces (don't forget the additional `;` at the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is another answer of mine, instead of adding comments under my previous answer.

`\tikz` is used when you only have a single line command, like `\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);`.

If you want to compile more than one line of commands, then you have to create a scope between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Your code as it is could work if you add two pairs of curly braces around your commands:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \tikz {\foreach \r in {0,1,2} {\foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \n using {int(\r*3+\c)}] in {0,1,2} \node at (\c,\r) {\n};}}
\end{document}
```

But it would be a better way to include all your code in a `tikzpicture` scope, like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r in {0,1,2}
        {
        \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \n using {int(\r*3+\c)}] in {0,1,2}
            \node at (\c,\r) {\n};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same but it's more legible.

Comment: You need the braces even inside a `tikzpicture`? Why?

Comment: You need to tell Ti*k*Z that the first `\foreach` has to loop all the following lines (here both the following lines).

Comment: The external braces of the `tikz` statement are redundant. The following compiles successfully, and the resulting PDF file displays as desired. `\tikz \foreach \r in {0,1,2} {\foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \n using {int(\r*3+\c)}] in {0,1,2} \node at (\c,\r) {\n};};`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with only one `\foreach` loop:

[image: only one foreach loop]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \x using {int(Mod(\i,3))}] in {0,...,8}
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\i/3}
            \node at (\x,\y) {\i};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I can't accept it, because it doesn't answer my question. I specifically wanted to know what the bug was in my code, not only in order to accomplish the task at hand, but also so I could learn to avoid a similar bug in the future. As Rmano pointed out [in their comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664905/using-tikzs-foreach-loop-to-write-a-square-of-numbers/665015#comment1653505_664905), the fact that the `foreach` does not create a group is an important lesson to learn from my question.

Comment: Actually, the most important issue in your code is that you used `\tikz` which is a shortcut for a single command. Hence nothing is interpreted as Ti*k*Z commands after your first `\foreach` loop. Secondly, you don't have to put the `\node` command into curly brackets but only the second `\foreach` loop in order to make it work. And finally, it's no big deal if you don't accept my answer but you should answer yourself so the question would be closed to inform everyone that it's solved.

Comment: Thanks. This is informative. 1. What do you mean by "nothing is interpreted as TikZ commands after your first `\foreach` loop"? How does the TikZ engine process my command? What does it think the second `\foreach` loop is when it sees it? 2. You wrote "you used `\tikz` which is a shortcut for a single command". Had I used `\tikzpicture` would my code have worked?

Comment: See my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done with a `matrix` and no `foreach`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    arraynode/.style={
        node contents={\the\numexpr3*(3-\pgfmatrixcurrentrow)+\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax},
        },
    array/.style={%
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes = arraynode,
        nodes in empty cells}, 
]

\matrix[array] {
&&\\
&&\\
&&\\};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]